# memcpy() modified client socket file descriptor

Tags: c, sockets

so im trying to send a structure between client and server.I defined a structure in both sides:

```
 struct msg {
    char name[50];
    char time[50];
    int len;
    char buf[200];
 }
```

The issue occurs in `server.c`.   I have already located the problem in this line:

```
 struct msg s1;
 char buffer_input[1024]={0};// the buffer stream for sending 
 ...// omitted all sorts of initializations cuz they all passed my debug and tests
 memset(buffer_input,0,sizeof(buffer_input));
 memcpy(buffer_input,&s1,sizeof(s1));
 /* Originally, the send() call read: */
 /* ssize_t size=send(client_sock,(struct sockaddr*)&client_sock_address,&addrlen); */
 ssize_t size=send(client_sock,buffer_input,sizeof(buffer_input),0);
 if(size<0) perror("send()");
```

then in the standard output, I have:

```
send() : Socket operations on non-socket object
```

so I have a hunch that `memcpy(buffer_input,&s1,sizeof(s1))` could be the cause. So I modified the code like:

```
 memset(buffer_input,0,sizeof(buffer_input));
 strcpy(buffer_input,"example");
```

The send() worked perfectly and I received messages in correct formats.

After a series of debugging, I realized that after `memcpy(...)`, the file descriptor of client socket turned `0` from `8`.

So I wonder, in what cases could `memcpy` modify file descriptor of sockets..

Comment: Please make sure that you have exactly copied the code that causes trouble so you don't have to edit the question when someone's answer suggests that there is a mistake in the code.  It makes it difficult for everyone.

Comment: What is `s1`; what is `sizeof(s1)`?  On the face of it, `sizeof(s1) > sizeof(buffer_input)` and therefore your `memcpy()` is trampling out of bounds and one of the bits it tramples on happens to be your file descriptor.  Add some asserts -- `assert(sizeof(s1) <= sizeof(buffer_input));`.  Then fix things when it fires.  Also, the message from `perror()` appears on `stderr`, not `stdout`, though the difference is hard to spot.  And, if the assertion doesn't fire, then your 'omitted all sorts of initializations' code is probably causing the trouble instead.  Print client_sock often as you go.

Answer (score 2):

`memcpy` should not, in *any* circumstances, modify file descriptors.

What it *may* do is overwrite memory if you give it incorrect parameters, which seems unlikely given the information we have (`s1` should be around 300 bytes, much less than the 1000 you allow for `buffer`).

The chances of your buffer being too small for your structure seems low, if that code is indeed what you have (both in terms of text and sequence, including not entering or exiting functions).

All I can suggest is debug code.

You need to, *before* calling `memcpy`, output the following values:

- `sizeof(buffer)`.
- `&buffer`.
- `sizeof (s1)`.
- `&s1`.
- `client_sock`.
- `&client_sock`.

Then output them again after the call. Based on that, we should be able to detect (or dispose of the possibility of) corruption by the `memcpy` call.

Answer (score 1):

Should the line

```
ssize_t size=send(client_sock,(struct sockaddr*)&client_sock_address,&addrlen);
```

read

```
ssize_t size=send(client_sock, buffer_input, 1024);
```

Or just get rid of `buffer_input` and have

```
ssize_t size=send(client_sock, &s1, sizeof(s1));
```

(you can also remove the memset stuff as well!)

**EDIT**

After some more coffee, here is a better solution:

```
/* 50 + 100 + 100 + 4 */
#define BUFFER_LENGTH 254

...

unsigned char buffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];

...

memcpy(buffer, s1.name, 50);
memcpy(buffer + 50, s1.time, 50);
uint32_t net_len = htonl(s1.len);
memcpy(buffer + 100, &net_len, 4);
memcpy(buffer + 104, ss1.buf, 100);

...

ssize_t size=send(client_sock, buffer, BUFFER_LEN);
```

Comment: i've edited my post.it was some typing error i did.send() is correct in this case

Comment: and whats more,i dont know if send() supports sending a structure as the way it sends off a buffer stream

Comment: @y26jin - You can send off a structure this way as it does not contain pointers. The only problem might be the endiness of the two machines, but for brevity and as the OP used `memcpy` I assume that the two machines in question are the same endiness. send just requires a series of bytes to xmit.

Comment: @Ed endian-ness isn't the only problem ... the two machines might also have different struct padding rules, or different sizeof(int) values.  Sending a structure this way isn't portable, and is likely to break unless the sending and receiving machines are very similar, and the compiled code was compiles with the same settings on each side.

Comment: @Jeremy - You right - better to serialise it. Did not have enough coffee by then!

Comment: @EdHeal i apologize for my 1st version uncaucious post.Is htonl() necessary?I suppose len is just the length of my buffer in the defined structure instead of an IP address.I guess what you do is to set up an official ending rule(in this case,nl or ns) for both clients and server.I wonder if it helps endings for structures...anyway im gonna give a shot on my pc after off from work :-)

Comment: @y26jin - The official ending rule is network order. The macros htonl, ntohl etc do this for you - thus you can communicate regardless of the endiness of the machines. (Note they are macros - usually - hence very low overhead)